# defaultdict of defaultdict of int

Tags: python, defaultdict

How do I do defaultdict(defaultdict(int))?

I tried the nested defaultdict method:

```
def ddict():
    return defaultdict(ddict)
```

I am looking to do the following:

`m['a']['b'] += 1`

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow - it's been a while. As a refresher, please read [ask]. "I tried the nested defaultdict method:" **How** did you try it? **What happened** when you tried that, and **how is that different** from what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

m = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
m['a']['b'] += 1
```

Note if you want more depth, you can still use a recursive approach:

```
def ddict(some_type, depth=0):
    if depth == 0:
        return defaultdict(some_type)
    else:
        return defaultdict(lambda: ddict(some_type, depth-1))

m = ddict(int, depth=2)
m['a']['b']['c'] += 1
```